# Nested select separated by var fails

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I think this is more of a general JS question than D3 specific. When I was working out how to do a nested selection in D3, I originally had:

```
var main = d3.select('#main');

main.selectAll('div')
    .data(data)
        .enter().append('div').classed("parent", true)

var child = main.selectAll('.parent')
    .data(function(d) { return d.children }) //=> can not read property 'children' of undefined
        .enter().append('div').classed("child", true)
```

After reading [some of the selection docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_data), I refactored to the following:

```
const main = d3.select('#main').selectAll('div')
    .data(data)
        .enter().append('div').classed("parent", true)

const child = main.selectAll('.parent')
    .data(function(d) { return d.children })
        .enter().append('div').classed("child", true)
```

I works and is producing the desired effect. My question is why does the second call to data loose it's reference to the data in `main` when I did it the first way?

EDIT: I did some additional testing with the following:

```
const main = d3.select('#galaxy');
main.selectAll('div').data(data);
console.log(main); //=> ut {_groups: Array(1), _parents: Array(1)}

const main2 = d3.select('#galaxy').selectAll('div').data(data);
console.log(main2); //=> ut {_groups: Array(1), _parents: Array(1), _enter: Array(1), _exit: Array(1)}
```

So it seems that the first way doesn't get `_enter` and `_exit` methods.

Comment: After a second look at your question's title I have a feeling that you're thinking that the different results are due to the use of `var` versus `const`. That's not the case.

Comment: @Gerardo, When I was testing I change everything to var's, just in case. I realise that that is not the issue.

Comment: I'm not following this your edit, I already explained the issue in my answer. On top of that, the problem in your edit is **another** problem (it's just a selection reference issue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data` method accepts three things:

1. An array;
2. A function;
3. Nothing.

According to the API, when you use a function (which is the case in your first approach), this function...

> ... will be evaluated for each group in order, being passed the **group’s parent datum** (d, which may be undefined), the group index (i), and the selection’s parent nodes (nodes), with this as the group’s parent element. (emphasis mine)

So, this function depends on the parent's datum. This can be seen in the [source code](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/src/selection/data.js#L94):

```
data = value.call(parent, parent && parent.__data__, j, parents)
```

And here comes the explanation for your question: in your first approach, your selection has no parent's data. You don't have multiple groups, which are typically created using a `selectAll` followed by another `selectAll`. All you have in your first approach is a `select` followed by a `selectAll`.

Let's show this in a simple demo:

```js
var data = [{
    name: "foo",
    value: 10
  },
  {
    name: "bar",
    value: 17
  },
  {
    name: "baz",
    value: 42
  }
];

var main = d3.select("body");

var parent = main.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('div')
  .classed("parent", true)

main.selectAll('.parent')
  .data(function(d) {
    console.log("parent's datum is: " + JSON.stringify(d))
    return 0;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

On the other hand, if you have a `selectAll`  followed by another `selectAll`, you have multiple groups:

```js
var data = [{
    name: "foo",
    value: 10
  },
  {
    name: "bar",
    value: 17
  },
  {
    name: "baz",
    value: 42
  }
];

var main = d3.select("body");

var parent = main.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('div')

parent.selectAll(null)
  .data(function(d) {
    console.log("parent's datum is: " + JSON.stringify(d))
    return d
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

For completeness, here is a table I made with the differences between `select` and `selectAll`, pay attention to "grouping":

**Table:** Differences between `select` and `selectAll`.

| Method | select() | selectAll() |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Selection | selects the first element that matches the selector string | selects all elements that match the selector string |
| Grouping | Does not affect grouping | Affects grouping |
| Data propagation | Propagates data | Doesn't propagate data |

Comment: Thanks for the details write up @Gerardo. I've added an edit, with an additional test I did to see what's happening.